# How do i change a date string from my left/right arrows, in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel 2010, I have a date "01-01-2012" and a left and right arrow.

I need to apply a macro or something else so the days in the date will decrease/increase accordingly. How can this be done?

Example:
"01-03-2012", when right-arrow is pressed, the date should change to "02-03-2012", and next time "03-03-2012" and so on.. from [01-31]
Note, the months and years shall never change.

I have made a macro, that can change the date the fixed date I typed in when recording the macro, but it's not good enough. I need it to add/substract instead.

Comment: is "dd-mm-yyyy" somehow saved in variables. I mean do u have 3 integers one for day,month and year or do you just want to use a string that has to be converted to integers and then back to a string?

Comment: Is this date in a sheet or in a userform? If it's in a sheet, I'm not sure how using the Arrow keys will help you because that is an essential part of navigation in Excel and you would be completely overriding native (and extremely common) functionality of Excel's navigation keys. I wouldn't recommend this approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I named the cell where the date is "theDate". The Sub for `SubtractDay` is pretty much the same, the second argument for the `DateAdd` function would be -1.

```
Sub AddDay()

Dim theDate As Date
Dim newDate As Date

theDate = Sheet1.Range("theDate")

newDate = DateAdd("d", 1, theDate))

Sheet1.Range("theDate") = newDate

End Sub
```

Please note that is a quick'n'dirty VBA Sub, since this is not my "forte", but it will work...

Comment: Can't you use your 'theDate', in this line 'newDate = DateAdd("d", 1, Sheet1.Range("theDate"))' like this instead? 'newDate = DateAdd("d", 1, theDate)' ?

Comment: Absolutely! Multitasking... best left to computers. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

This can definitely be done via a VBA macro.

Under the Developer Tab -> Visual Basic, Double click on the sheet where the cell in question exists, and implement the following event:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

End Sub
```

The parameter Target would contain the cell that was selected (check if one of the arrows is the selected cell), then de-/in- crease the date value accordingly.